# Building a calendar webapp syncing with Google Calendar, Outlook and Apple Calendar

Tags: outlook, synchronization, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am about to build a simple webapp that has several tasks, each of which has got a due date.

I would like this webapp to automatically sync with Google Calendar, Outlook and Apple Calendar - 2-way integration would be a plus.

The webapp is built on a LAMP server.

What's the cleverest way I can go about this from a point of view of limiting the workload as much as possible?

And also, is that even possible? I wasn't able to find an API for Outlook or Apple Calendar.

Is CalDev the answer? Is there any product/software that will do that automatically, so that I need only to sync with it and it will do the rest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

- Synchronize your proprietary calendar with Google Calendar (make this your "master calendar") using the GCal API; if your application can produce a valid ICS file then you can import it directly to Google Calendar. As this feature is discontinued by Google you can use some online WebDAV based import/export service (I use for this [Synqya](https://synqya.appspot.com))
- Use the WebDAV access to the Google Calendar to synchronize Outlook and Apple Calendar with it using their calendar subscription features (this would be one way sync). If you need secured access to GCal and 2-way sync, it will involve further steps.